# NokiaX Android "Error initializing map: p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m with disk cache"

Tags: android, here-api, nokiax

Everything was working fine, all of a sudden I started to get this exception.

```
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing map: problem with disk cache
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity$1.onFactoryInitializationCompleted(MapActivity.java:152)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at com.nokia.maps.MapFactory$2.run(MapFactory.java:455)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4807)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
09-20 12:54:08.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4127):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I then tried to load the Here app, I got a error as well

> There was a problem just then. Try again later.

The sad part is, that there is no place to catch this exception and end gracefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot the phone and it starts to work. Seems like HERE maps gets corrupted from time to time, and all associated applications will crash, with no hopes of coding in a way to gracefully exit. I hope there is a place to log bugs with NokiaX, as of now there does not seem to be any.

Answer (score 0):

if this is happening with emulator, then simply check that the emulator environment has SD card defined, and if it did have, you could of course try cleaning the emulator environment. It should work just fine, thus resetting it would definitely help.

If it is happening in a device, do try out with Maps application whether there is issues with maps data in it. That app might give better error description and maybe ways on solving the issue.

Comment: Its happening on the device, and the error description is `There was a problem just then. Try again later.`. I am afraid its not better than this.